# How do I disable the autocorrect bar on Android keyboards?

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

The problem is the autocorrect bar on the Android soft keyboard is covering my ListView (on one phone only!). I'm hoping to fix this by simply removing the autocorrect bar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this inputType : InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS, you can add it with a "|" in the xml and in java if you have already an inputType on your view.

Comment: @QuentonJones: And bear in mind that it might not be honored by all input method editors. Just as other developers do not get to dictate terms on how your app looks, you do not get to dictate terms as to how the input method editor looks. It is up to that IME's developer as to what `inputType` options the IME will support.

Comment: Oh the joys of programming for Android :/